# CameraX - Finding Focal Lengths for android Device

Tags: android

It took some time to figure out the focal length of a camera in android , so posting this so it helps others .

CameraManagerCompat.from(this).unwrap().getCameraCharacteristics("0").get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)

Comment: thanks!  but I just get 
*CameraManagerCompat.from can only be called from within the same library (androidx.camera:camera-camera2)*

Comment: Add @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") on top of the function

Answer (score 2):

CameraManagerCompat.from(this).unwrap().getCameraCharacteristics("0").get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS)